# Cannot install cstore_fdw on docker postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, cstore-fdw

Trying to install cstore_fdw on a docker postgres container just to test the columnar functionality, and I'm stuck at the point of build/make the cstore repo.

The os is debian 9, postgres 11, i've installed make and a few tools I need.

The step where you build and run the make cmd, is failing bcz of postgres.  Found in "building" section here: https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw

Directories
cstore dir:  /var/lib/postgresql/cstore_fdw/
pg config dir: /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf

at the cstore dir I run the following and get the following error, and I don't know why.

`PATH=/var/lib/postgresql/data/:$PATH make`

`Makefile:38: /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory`
`Makefile:45: *** PostgreSQL 9.3 or 9.4 or 9.5 or 9.6 or 10 or 11 is required to compile this extension.  Stop.`

I've also tried to use the pg bin directory in the make cmd, which is /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/, I think, and that gives same error.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your docker image does not contain the PostgreSQL extension building infrastructure PGXS.

You will need to install that and the PostgreSQL header files.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, will give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have solved it, this article showed what i needed, https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw/issues/209   And it appears I was missing gcc   https://dbtut.com/index.php/2018/11/25/make-gcc-command-not-found-make-oracle_fdw-o-error-127/  Still have to verify but now it appears to have built.  Thanks @Laurenz Albe